# EF: how to eager load associations correctly

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using EF for Data Access in my App. Data Model (greatly simplified):

```
class Project 
{
  virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos {get;set;}
  virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars {get;set;}
  // actually I have many more kinds of Project's data
}

class Foo 
{
  virtual Project Project {get;set;}
  virtual ICollection<Bar> LinkedBars {get;set;}
  //And they are greatly intervened with each other
}
//etc etc.
```

Point is:

- All `Foo`, `Bar` etc etc have references to each other
- This references never leaves `Project`, i.e. following is always right:
  `foo.Bars.All(bar => bar.Project == foo.Project) == true`

I load projects as follows:

```
var project = Db.Set<Project>
              .Include(p => p.Foos)
              .Include(p => p.Bars);
```

So, after that, if I accessing some `foo.Bars` I trigger lazy load. That's expected, after all, I have eagerly loaded all required data from `Project`, `Foo` and `Bar`, but not `Foo_Bar` link table.

Let's modify:

```
var project = Db.Set<Project>
              .Include(p => p.Foos.Select(f => f.Bars))
              .Include(p => p.Bars);
```

Now I have all required data in memory, but (!) generated SQL is clearly not optimal. Actually, EF is loading `Project`, `Foo`, `Foo_Bar` tables and scans `Bar` twice — once for p.Bars and once for foo.Bars. So, I can't eager load `foo.Bar_Ids` without eager loading `foo.Bars`, can I?

What should I do to improve?

Comment: And we are hiring C# developers in St. Petersburg, Russia :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK only way to obtain this is to declare Foo_Bars as explicit link table (not autogenerated by EF6), and `Include` it